# splice method in JavaScript removing two elements from array last index

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

```
const arr2 = ["one" , "two" , "three"];

const removedElements = arr2.splice(-1 , 2 , "four" , "five");

console.log(arr2 , removedElements)
```

I am trying to remove two elements from the last index of arr2 using splice but only one element is getting removed . how to delete last two elements in array using splice.

Comment: I am getting output ['one', 'two', 'four', 'five'] ['three']   only one element is getting removed even i placed the delete count as two

Answer (score 0):

the first parameter is starting index so it starts at the last index and removes 2 but it has only on value next to it so you should start at -2

```
const arr2 = ["one" , "two" , "three"];

const removedElements = arr2.splice(-2 , 2 , "four" , "five");

console.log(arr2 , removedElements)
// ["one" , "four" , "five"]["two" , "three"]
```

Comment: No need to answer duplicate questions